# Swift3 get element from array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, string

I have a json string converted to string array like below:

```
    let str = "{ \"dtResult\": [ { \"itmdtl_item_no\": \"AO406705959SE3\" }, { \"itmdtl_item_no\": \"AO406708959SE3\" } ] }"
    let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]

        let result = json["dtResult"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? [ ]
        let item = result[0] as! [String:Any]

        print(item)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

When i print out the result of item, i got the value like this:

["itmdtl_item_no": AO406705959SE3]

But i just want the string "AO406705959SE3", how can i do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't write

```
let result = json["dtResult"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? [ ]
```

If `result` is `nil` or empty the app will crash on `result[0]`

Instead write to check if the array exists and is not empty

```
if let result = json["dtResult"] as? [[String:Any]], !result.isEmpty {
   let item = result[0] as! [String:Any]
   // Now get the value for key "itmdtl_item_no"
   if let itemNo = item["itmdtl_item_no"] as? String {
       print(itemNo)
   }
}
```